Add a C# source file to a project via command line
I'm trying to add C# source files to a .NET project (.csproj) using the command line. Ideally, I would like to avoid manually editing the .csproj file and use a command to add files.
The most straightforward command seems to be dotnet add <project-name>.csproj <source-file>.cs, but this command is only for adding nuget-packages and references to other projects, it seems.
Is there any command that can help me automate adding C# source files to the project file? Or do I need to always edit the .csproj manually? If the latter, is there any recommended approach for this?

Why do want that? In newer .net version .cs-files are being picked up automatically. They don't need to be added to the .csproj-file.

Could you tell me how I can find out whether this is supported in my version? I'm using SDK 8, and my my project file is certainly not picking up on the files automatically. My IDE is adding the items manually with <Compile Include=.../> -- problem is, it only does so for files that are actually generated from within the IDE, not for all the files that are generated externally, so I'd like a way to automate that. (I could manually add them one-by-one via the UI of my IDE, but that's insanity ^^)

It's been supported since .NET Core 1 IIRC - it's certainly supported in .NET 8.

If the files are external to your project, then you can avoid adding them one by one with a glob <Compile Include="TheFolder\**\*.cs" />. Then it's a one-time manual edit.

Could you please share your *.csproj file and an example relative path of *.cs file you are attempting to include? Edit these into your question. Also consider stating that the automatic inclusion does not happen to you and possibly add an example line that IDE adds for you. That being said - what IDE do you use? Could you also run dotnet build and see if everything is as expected? (i.e. you get compile errors of missing types or ildasm shows that the types are/not included in the assembly).

As suggested in comment, C# files would be picked up automatically.
Just execute this snippet:
dotnet new console
'public static class StaticClass { public static string GetString() => "hello"; }' >> StaticClass.cs
'Console.WriteLine(StaticClass.GetString());' >> .\Program.cs
dotnet run

would output expected
Hello, World!
hello


You can use this command bellow:
dotnet new class -n Teste --project .\Project\Project.csproj -o .\Project

Explanation:
This command creates a new C# class file within a specified project. Here's a breakdown of each part:

dotnet new class: This command is used to create a new class file in a .NET project. The class template generates a basic .cs class file.

-n Teste: The -n or --name option specifies the name of the class you want to create. In this case, it will create a class named Teste.

--project .\Project\Project.csproj: This argument tells the command where to find the .csproj file (project file) that the class should be added to. The .\Project\Project.csproj is the path to the project file. It ensures that the class will be part of the specified project.

-o .\Project: The -o or --output option specifies the output directory where the class will be created. Here, it's placing the class in the Project folder.



Please [edit] your answer to explain what the command and its arguments do, so that you’re helping educate future readers.

You can use the following command in a C# project folder, it will create a file called Hello.cs
dotnet new class --name Hello

